# Incorrect string encoding in kotlin application main method arguments

Tags: kotlin, encoding, utf-8, android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating a small music player with kotlin and compose for desktop.

so it happens that i have a song with some weird encoding:  "08. ±ªþ³§ (feat. Yonaka).mp3"

```
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            val encodedArgument = "08. ±ªþ³§ (feat. Yonaka).mp3"
            args += listOf(encodedArgument)

        }
    }
}
```

when i receive it the main function args i get:    "08. ±??³§ (feat. Yonaka).mp3"

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = application {
    val arg = args[0] // this gives the value  "08. ±??³§ (feat. Yonaka).mp3"

}
```

so the file is not found and the program is crashing because of encoding issues.
i tried re-encoding it to UTF-8 and many other charsets but none of them gave the correct result.

**Update**

Eventually i was able to solve it.
On windows, i had to change my Region Settings > Current System Locale > to English (United States). apparently it affects the way the cmd translates unicode characters, so that fixed the argument being changed.
Also, because this argument is saved to a file and then gets read again later, i had to save it with charset of ISO_8859_1 so i could read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i was able to solve it. On windows, i had to change my Region Settings > Current System Locale > to English (United States). apparently it affects the way the cmd translates unicode characters, so that fixed the argument being changed. Also, because this argument is saved to a file and then gets read again later, i had to save it with charset of ISO_8859_1 so i could read correctly.